Debugging syntax highlighting - trying to mix C and TT2
I've tried to create syntax file for C code generated via Perl's Template::Toolkit 2, using same sourcing like as in tt2html.vim - just changed html.vim to c.vim (those are all in standard distribution - Vim 9.0 Patches: 1-1968). However, TT2 highlighting, despite contained arguments to it's definitions, somehow "leaks" to top-level so that C highlighting is wrong after C-preprocessor part, as seen in screenshot
I've tried to comment out syn cluster cPreProcGroup add=@tt2_top_cluster and no change. Also tried to change order - source c.vim after tt2.vim, but just got highlighting wrong the other way :) Below syntax file is second version (c after tt2).
I have a little snippet in my .vimrc showing current syntax element on F10 press, and it show that tt2_bracket_b is the problem, in both variants.
Screenshots of the issue:
C before tt2:

C after tt2:

Sample C code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <dev/usb/usbhid.h>
#include <dev/usb/usb_ioctl.h>

[% DEFAULT varname = 'string' %]
int
main(int [% argc %], char *argv[])
{
 int fd, r;
 struct usb_gen_descriptor ugd;

 if (argc != 2 || argv[1][0] == '-') {
  printf("Usage: zytemp UHIDDEVICE\n");
  exit(0);
 }

 fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
 if (fd == -1) {
  fprintf(stderr, "open(\"%s\"): %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
  exit(1);
 }

 memset(&ugd, 0, sizeof(ugd));
 ugd.ugd_data = "\xc4\xc6\xc0\x92\x40\x23\xdc\x96";
 /* key for subsequent reads */
 ugd.ugd_maxlen = 8;
 ugd.ugd_report_type = UHID_FEATURE_REPORT;

 r = ioctl(fd, USB_SET_REPORT, &ugd);
 if (r) { perror("ioctl(USB_SET_REPORT)"); }
 
 return 0;
}

Syntax file ~/.vim/syntax/tt2c.vim (corresponds to second screen):
if exists("b:current_syntax")
    finish
endif

runtime! syntax/tt2.vim
unlet b:current_syntax

runtime! syntax/c.vim
unlet b:current_syntax

" syn cluster cPreProcGroup add=@tt2_top_cluster

let b:current_syntax = "tt2c"

So, the main question is probably of not a particular highlighting, but about how Vim applies syntax rules? How to debug them? I tried vim -V and even vim -V40 but with no luck.
Next, I tried to ditch out sourcing tt2.vim and adding rules from it by small chunks, even guarding everything with contained containedin=tt2_tag_region - but still got e.g. tt2_func leaked outside of [% %] tags region applied to just some (!) C functions... it it time to suspect bug in Vim?..

Welcome to Vim! Your question is of course very valid and I'm sure one of our expert will do its best to answer it. But I wonder why you want to introduce your own C syntax file. Could you tell us why the standard one provided with Vim is not fitting the bill?

@VivianDeSmedt I was exactly trying to reuse two standard files from Vim, however, this did not work as expected, as can be seen from screenshots. If I haven't clarified it enough, I need TWO syntaxes simultaneously in one file, one for C and one for TT2. Such combination exists in Vim for TT2 and HTML (where it works OK), but not a C and TT2 combination, and I tried to create it by just replacing html to c in copy of tt2html, but this paints wrong.

Thanks for your feedback. There were already some questions about the same topic. I'll try to find them fir you.

You could be interested reading this answer.
